# invoking a doubleclick event

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How do I trigger a "ondblClickRow" event in jqGrid? I need to invoke the double click event handler of the row on a click of a button.

```
button:
<a class="btn" id="shwDetails" type="button>Details</a>

grid:
$("#gridX").jqgrid({
...
...
ondblClickRow : function(rowID, iRow, iCol, e){
// event handler
fetchRowData(rowID);
}

...
...
});
```

The following doesn't seem to be working.

```
$('#gridX').trigger( 'jqGridDblClickRow' ); 
$('#gridX').trigger( 'ondblClickRow' );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried $('#gridX').trigger('ondblClickRow'); ?

Comment: I did try that. That doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I your special case you can just call the function `fetchRowData` directly instead of "trigger a `ondblClickRow` event".

If some other code create jqGrid and you really need to "trigger" callback function `ondblClickRow` (not an event) you can do the following:

```
var ondblClickRowHandler = $("#gridX").jqGrid("getGridParam", "ondblClickRow");

ondblClickRowHandler.call($("#gridX")[0], rowID);
```

Comment: @VaZaA: You are welcome! The problem is that jqGrid support callback methods lake `ondblClickRow` which will be wrong named "events" in the documentation and real jQuery events like `jqGridDblClickRow`. One can define **only one** callback, but one can bind **multiple** event handler. Look at [the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L2491-L2499) which uses both. So if you really need to call callback function defined by jqGrid option `ondblClickRow` you can follow my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Does the ondblClickRow need one, some or all of those variables?

```
var rowID =  ,//your rowID
    iRow =  ,//your iRow 
    iCol =  ,//your iCol
    e; 
$('#gridX').trigger( 'jqGridDblClickRow', [rowID, iRow, iCol, e]);
```

docs here: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

careful, though:

> "The event object is always passed as the first parameter to an event
>   handler, but if additional parameters are specified during a
>   .trigger() call, these parameters will be passed along to the handler
>   as well. To pass more than one parameter, use an array as shown here.
>   As of jQuery 1.6.2, a single parameter can be passed without using an
>   array."